# akka http, charset header, utf-8 issue

Tags: scala, character-encoding, akka, spray, akka-http

I have this route:

```
path("rus") {
  complete("Привет!")
}
```

When i go /rus with browser (chrome) i get this output:

> "ÐŸÑ€Ð¸Ð²ÐµÑ‚!"

Why? Response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: akka-http/2.4.10
Date: Mon, 10 Oct 2016 22:31:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 15
```

I used to use spray but now i want akka http, i didn't face an issue like this one.

When i curl this path i get normal output

```
$ curl http://localhost:9010/rus
"Привет!"
```

I see that response header 'Content-Type' shoud be 'application/json;charset=utf-8' but charset is missing...

Comment: What are the response headers in spray? and what version of akka-http you're using? Here are the discussions on this topic https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/17409 https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/19260

Comment: I use  akka http 2.4.11. response header in spray has 'charset: utf-8' that's why it works there... I saw that topics but i didn't understand why they are closed and what is the solution. As i understood it's browser bug because application/json has utf-8 by default, but i don't get it why i can't specify 'charset: utf-8' explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found method withParams. Now it works

```
HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/json`.withParams(Map("charset" -> "utf-8"))), "Привет".getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this is [a bug in chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=438464). The `charset` parameter must be ignored for the `application/json` content-type according to its [IANA registration](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/json):

> Note:  No "charset" parameter is defined for this registration.
>      Adding one really has no effect on compliant recipients.